# Android simulate key press-2

Tags: android

[Android simulate key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696489/android-simulate-key-press/8696700#8696700) ; I want to apply this answer to my app which when call activity was started number pressed itself but I have problem with these , how can I fix it I cannot find ,If there exist please share link .

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:090"));
            startActivity(i);
new Thread(new Runnable() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
            for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        }   
    }).start();
```

Comment: I think, I change activity and I should send or create thread on Action_Call activity but HOW ?

Comment: IT IS NOT DUPLICATE QUESTION .