# HTML5 video not starting automatically in Amazon WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, html5-video, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying to develop a video app for the Amazon FireTV using the Amazon WebView component. I cannot make the videos play automatically and I have tried using the HTML5 video DOM properties and events and also setting the video tag property *autoplay="autoplay"*. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test player</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                console.log('DOM Loaded!');
                var player = document.getElementById('video-player');
                player.autostart = true;
                player.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
                player.load();
                player.addEventListener("canplay", function () { console.log('play'); document.getElementById('video-player').play(); }, false);
            }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video style="background: #e0e0e0; width: 400px; height: 320px;" id="video-player" controls="controls" src="" autoplay="autoplay" >Your browser does not support Video rendering</video>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

The Java code for initializing the WebView is as follows (in the onCreate method):

```
this.wrapper = (AmazonWebView) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
factory.initializeWebView(this.wrapper, 0xFFFFFF, false, null);

this.wrapper.setFocusable(false); // Never allow focus on the WebView because it blocks the Play/Pause, Fast Forward and Rewind buttons

AmazonWebChromeClient webClient = new AmazonWebChromeClient();

this.wrapper.setWebChromeClient(webClient); // Needed in order to use the HTML5 <video> element
AmazonWebSettings browserSettings = this.wrapper.getSettings();
browserSettings.setPluginState(AmazonWebSettings.PluginState.ON);
browserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
this.wrapper.addJavascriptInterface(new JSChannel(this.wrapper), "appChannel");
browserSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I have also set internet permissions and hardware acceleration in the manifest. Do I need to add something to the Java code in order for the videos to play automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like both Amazon and Android WebView require, by default, a gesture from the user (a key or button press) to start the media playback. This behavior can be changed by calling the [*setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)) method of the *WebSettings* object, like this:

```
AmazonWebSettings browserSettings = webView.getSettings();
browserSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

This way you can play/pause the video using JavaScript code in your HTML5 app (not using Java):

```
document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
    this.play();
    console.log('canplaythrough: Player started');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

FireTV, like Android in general, does not support Autoplay of videos in HTML5 (yes, a pain I know)

To get around this you will need to fire a video.play() message via the Javascript bridge from the container apk (and I do this in response to a loadedmetadata event in the HTML, though you could, eg, use canPlayThrough or other events to trigger it)

in Java:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void vidLoaded() {
    WebViewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById(\"video-player\").play();");
        }
    });
    Log.v(TAG, "Start playing video via Java Bridge");
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
document.getElementById("video-player").addEventListener('loadedmetadata', vidLoad, false);
....
function vidLoad() {
    document.getElementById("video-player").removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', vidLoad, false)
    // use a Java method to trigger "play" on the video via JavaScriptInterface
    appChannel.vidLoaded();
}
```

Comment: In my case it seems that not even by running JavaScript code from the JavascriptInterface object does not work. And that seems to be because I didn't call the [setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)) method of the WebSettings object.

Comment: Also, a way to simulate the key press event is by using the Instrumentation object as mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696489/android-simulate-key-press#8696700)