# Trigger a keypress from code in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a custom Android device that has additional hardware buttons. Those buttons are used to trigger a barcode scanner on the device.

I am trying to trigger the keypress from code so far i tried:

```
MainActivity.Instance.DispatchKeyEvent ( new Android.Views.KeyEvent(
   Android.Views.KeyEventActions.Down, 
   Android.Views.Keycode.Eisu
));
```

`Eisu` is 211 which is my button's keycode.

But this gives me nothing. Has anyone managed this?

### Edit

I also tried with instrumentation:

```
await Task.Run (delegate {
   Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
   inst.SendKeyDownUpSync (Android.Views.Keycode.Eisu);
});
```

No luck on this... I am guessing that the events get dispatched but somehow no context catches them.

This is called from `DependencyService` in `xamarin.forms`, could it be a problem?

Comment: [Android Simulate Key Press here on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696489/android-simulate-key-press) ... [Xamarin api for Instrumentation](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Instrumentation.SendKeyDownUpSync(Android.Views.Keycode))

Comment: Thanks, Actually I did try this, see my update.

Comment: Nobody knows the answer to this?