# Android handle virtual Direction pad on screen to focus view

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing an app can visible Direction pad on the screen, but I don't know how to handle or override action like UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT to focus the next view (like some buttons in image below).

[image: Here are image description]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to what I need here [Android simulate key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696489/android-simulate-key-press)
. Use Instrumentation class to sendKeyEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Set this tow attributes for your view items :

1. android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
2. android:background="@drawable/bg_view"

**where bg_view.xml is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
        <solid android:color="#1F1F3E" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#1F1F3E" />
    </shape>
</item>
```